# How to generate bot paths in Team Fortress 2

Tags: team-fortress-2

How do I generate paths for the offline bots in Team Fortress 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you enable the developer console.

Then you load a map and hit the <kbd>`</kbd> key to open the console.

In the console, type in `nav_generate`.

It should generate bot paths. Then reload the map.